# No option for serverless V1 in AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm getting the message:

> Currently, query editor only supports Aurora Serverless databases. Only Aurora Serverless database that you have access to will be displayed.
>
> To use the query editor for a database, the database must have the Data API enabled.

Trying to use the query editor in AWS.

I tried creating an Aurora serverless database, but there seems to be no option to select Serverless V1

[image]

I only ever see Serverless V2. I'm in Europe (London), so it should be available: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.Aurora_Fea_Regions_DB-eng.Feature.ServerlessV1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serverless v1 only works with very specific engine versions, e.g. for Aurora PostgreSQL you can get it for 11.16 but not 11.17 or 11.18. When you pick one of the appropriate versions in the Create Database dialog, then you'll get the Serverless choice under Instance Class. You can see the relevant versions in the info panel on the right side - click the Info link for the 'Available versions' field.

Comment: Thank you, I picked out a few versions to try work out if that was an issue, but the sample I picked out must have missed the ones that allowed v1!